# Why does The Trainman wear so many watches?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), The Trainman is shown wearing nine wristwatches, each set to different times.

[image]

Why does The Trainman wear so many watches?

Comment: No help in the [script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/the-matrix-revolutions-2003.pdf); *514 INT. SUBWAY STATION ONE - PASSENGER TUNNELS - NIGHT: *He [The Trainman] *bounds up the stairwell, and zig-zags through the mostly-deserted tunnels that lead up to interconnecting stations. **Checking a wrist full of watches,** he veers off towards another staircase. Almost flying he hurls himself down the stairs to the train platform below.*

Comment: The [wiki article on the Trainman](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Trainman) claims (without any visible justification, as far as I can tell) that "*He also wears multiple watches on his arm to track the movements of each train*"

Comment: That's how people worked with different time zone when there wasn't smartphones yet.

Comment: Maybe he needs to [check the time more than once...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIUytVfDrDg)

Comment: Ramakandran (at Mobil Ave.) is wearing a watch that says ten past six. None of The Trainman's visible watches have that time.